# throwing roses in the museum gallery to slack-jawed guests

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

The Associated Press (AP) has printed the following story, where the boldfaced "to" is used:

> PARIS (AP) — A man seemingly disguised as an old woman in a wheelchair threw a piece of cake at the glass protecting the Mona Lisa at the Louvre Museum and shouted at people to think of planet Earth...

> The man, whose identity was unknown, was also seen throwing roses in the museum gallery **to** slack-jawed guests.

https://www.usnews.com/news/entertainment/articles/2022-05-30/man-in-wig-throws-cake-at-glass-protecting-mona-lisa

However, on the Twitter page of an eyewitness to the incident, the preposition "at" is used in the caption:

> A picture of him captured throwing roses **at** me.

https://twitter.com/lukeXC2002/status/1530972976501366785?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw

I thought the distinction between "throw something **to** someone" and "throw something **at** someone" is clear cut, but why do the above sources not agree with each other? Is either of them in the wrong?

Comment: Perhaps they were written by different people who had different experiences.

Comment: Which preposition would be more reasonable, given the overall context?

Comment: Throwing gifts to friends is generous. At them, no thank you. A reporter might describe throwing roses to visitors while I think he threw them at me, not to me as to a stage actor.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Why did you say "A reporter might describe throwing roses to visitors "? Were you saying it's a journalist usage?

Comment: *Throwing to* is likely neutral, and *throwing at* is likely negative. Using one over the other amounts to opinion. Reporters have their opinion, but it's not journalistic. Were I the Mona Lisa with cake thrown *at* me or the Madonna with dung thrown *at* me, I'd never say that sh&t was thrown *to* me like the bouquet for cheering bridesmaids.

Comment: Some say "throw something to someone" means throwing something in the expectation that the other person catches it. Is that true? But nowhere in the article do we see such an expectation.

Answer (score 3):

"To" can be used by an observer who views the thrower sympathetically, and "at" by someone less supportive.

Comment: Does the article suggest the author is sympathetic to the thrower's stance in any other way?